# Upgrade Visual studio solution VS2010->VS2017:

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build the Postgresql odbc driver in VS2017.
The existing project and solution is a VS2010 project.

When I re-targeted the solution and project, I have problems:

1. x64 (Release, Debug) builds ok
2. x86 (Release, Debug) does not build:
   error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of Release|Win32.

But I have checked: not any Win32 in project and solution files, only x86 and x64.

3. In the VS 2017 solution explorer: when I select the x86 I see the project name as "pgodbc (Visual Studio 2010)", when I select x64 I see "pgodbc".

What do I need to check/change?

Comment: You need to check `Configuration manager` and to make sure that 32 bit platform is actually supported by this library. Maybe 32 bit variant needs retargeting, you cast select toolset in project properties.

Comment: I have made Retarget Solution, and the project was retargeted to the Toolset 141. The x64 (Release, Debug) can be build, ok. But the problem is with x86

Comment: So is x86 variant retargeted or not?

Comment: I have selected the configuration x86, then retarget project, it was completed BUT: in the explorer I see still pgodbc(Visual Studio 2010) and cannot build, the same error

Comment: You should open project properties for x86 Release configuration and check whether it is targeting VS2017 or not.

Comment: I see that for x86 Project->Properties->Configuration Type = Application(exe). I change it to Dynamic Library, save, close, then open: it is still Application(exe). Miracle...

Comment: You are right! x86: Project->Properties->Platofrm Toolset:  VS2010, I change to VS2017, click Apply and the old value is restored: again VS2010...

Comment: save, exit, backup and then load the .vcxproj file into a text editor.  Search for the offending target "Release|Win32".  See if the target has overrides for the main setting of Toolset or other differences other than bitness between the 32bit and 64bit targets. Sometimes it is just easier reading the XML in the .vcxproj to resolve these things.

Comment: There is my project file, probably you can see what is incorrect: https://send.firefox.com/download/0d8ee45cd5/#NHkJDbC0ZGJ8EA6fkiVuxA